# Converting Native NetCDF to Gridded NetCDF3

Tags: netcdf, weather, atmosphere, noaa

Attempting to access raw NEXRAD data in native NetCDF format from the NOAA servers (i.e. thredds-aws, Amazon, etc.) and convert them to a gridded NetCDF file for post-processing automatically.

NOAA's [Weather and Climate Toolkit](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/wct/install.php) is able to export a gridded NetCDF3 file (in dropbox folder below).

I have trained an external code to process the exported gridded files. But, to automate this process and analyze several years for my research, I must figure out how to convert a native file from the NOAA servers into this gridded format. Specifically, I would like to have an MxN array in the final output file for the 'reflectivity', in dBz, of the lowest elevation scan angle, ~0.5 degrees, with 1D arrays of size M and N for Latitude and Longitude, respectively.

To assist in understanding what I'm looking for, here is a folder with two files in it. The one titled "KDOX_Gridded_V06_20170601_190648.nc", is the format I am seeking, and the other one is the RAW, native NetCDF that is easily accessible via online servers:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zgpb318ncpif894/AAAuBLsjC0_BRfB0T7peJk9ca?dl=0

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think PyArt might have what you want in its [map_to_grid](http://arm-doe.github.io/pyart-docs-travis/user_reference/generated/pyart.map.map_to_grid.html) functionality. This [example](http://arm-doe.github.io/pyart/dev/auto_examples/mapping/plot_map_one_radar_to_grid.html#example-mapping-plot-map-one-radar-to-grid-py) in particular seems relevant to what you're looking to do. After gridding, you'll probably have to write some code to manually create the netCDF structure you're looking for, unless it happens to match PyArt's gridded data model.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with DopplerShift that most likely you have to make your own code to get the wished output.

Namely, in input file you have Reflectivity(scanR, radialR, gateR) with dimensions Reflectivity(3,360,1332), but in output Reflectivity(time, lat, lon) and dimensions Reflectivity(1,800,497). I suspect no tool is able to see with just one-two steps that it needs to convert input from initial dimensions to completely another size (and of course the names).

Basically, you could just start by:

- cutting the variable you need
- renaming the dimensions/coordinate variables
- interpolating from initial coordinates to new ones